# How to load CSS stylesheet in Wordpress theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

How do I load (enqueue?) my custom CSS so that the content from my pages (which is inputted dynamically via Wordpress) has the CSS that my header and footer have?

I have a functions.php with the following, but it doesn't do anything except print the code at the top of my theme template in HTML.

```
function custom_style() {
    if ( is_page_template( 'templates/home.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'home', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/styles.css' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_style' );
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to get it so that each of my pages has the CSS that the header and footer have?

Answer (score 1):

If this were happening to me I would first clear the browser cache - have you tried this?

Your functions.php file looks syntactically correct. If you want your style applied to all pages (or to be the default) you don't need:

```
if (is_page_template(...)
```

Unless all of your pages use your home.php template.

If this is your theme's main stylesheet it should be included in the root directory with a header noting [these required points](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/main-stylesheet-style-css/). It can then be references like this:

```
function my_style(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_style');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a css file will be included between  tags, then one of the best aproaches is to make a css folder inside your theme folder, save your .css file there, and then, in your functions.php file, add only this one line of code:

```
wp_enqueue_style('handle', 'src', 'deps', 'ver', 'media');
```

Where:
Handle: unique name for the stylesheet,
Src: full path to your stylesheet,
Deps: dependencies for this file,
Ver: version number,
Media: where the styles will be applied (screen, print, etc)

Here is the link to the official docs:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/